# Calculate the Big-O for loop halve x and a nested loop inside it

Tags: java, algorithm

```
for(int i=n; i > 0; i=i/2)
    for(int j=i; j > 0; j=j/2)
        ...
```

For this loop, what should be the Big O?
And why?
I think the nested loop will run log(n) + log(n/2) + ... + 1
But not sure how to add them up

Comment: What do *you* think it is? (It is impossible to say without knowing what is inside the loop).

Comment: Already update. Inside the nested loop there is nothing.

Comment: But the we only set "n" here, why the answer will include i?

Comment: Hint: `log(n/2) = log n - log 2`

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop is `log N` as it goes around log<sub>2</sub>(N) times.

The inner loop is a variation on log N.

Over all, you could call it O((log N)<sup>2</sup>) as an upper bound. i.e.

let M = log<sub>2</sub>(n)

The sum is `M + (M-1) + ... 1` or `M * (M + 1) / 2` which is as an order is O(M<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: For the inner loop I think log(n) + log(n/2) + ... can be rewritten as log( n+ n/2 + n/4...) = log (n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...)) = log(cn) = log(n). So the Big O for it is O(log(n)) and we sum up get the total O(log(n)) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n)). Why is log(log(n)^2)? Still confused

Comment: @Chen log2(16) = 4, log2(8) = 3, log2(16 * 8) = 7, log2(16 + 8) ~= 4.58, so you cannot rewrite log2(n) +log2(n/2) as log2(n + n/2) but log2(n * n / 2)